# XAML-Designer is broken / package repository defect

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, designer

I have worked several weeks with Visual Studio 2013 Upd 4 and Universal Apps for Windows Phone 8.1 / Windows Store 8.1 without any problems. Last week suddendly the XAML-Designer is not working anymore.

```
System.Exception

Das Paketrepository ist beschädigt.

   bei Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   bei Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, FrameworkName targetFramework, String identifier, String baseDirectory)
   bei Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   bei Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   bei Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   bei Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   bei Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExpressionHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   bei Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   bei Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry)
   bei Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   bei Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   bei Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.<StartTask>b__6()
   bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

If i use Blend instead to open my XAML-file i get the same error.

I started a repair process of VS 2013, i reinstalled it ... nothing helps.

Any ideas how to repair the package repository ?

Comment: http://davidarodriguez.com/2013/04/25/unable-to-run-window-store-applications-after-compilation-in-visual-studio-the-package-repository-is-corrupted/ ?

Comment: Thx, BCdotWEB ... but these are not good news. :(